# CSS Flexbox dynamic height change on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm creating the `NotificationDrawer` component for Patternfly-React.
One of my finals to-dos was to make the drawer change its height dynamically when the window gets resized.

`drawer-pf` does change its height but its children doesn't. **the rule is to keep the Read/Clear buttons and other panels visible at all times.**
I managed to solve this issue with JS with an event listener injecting inline css to the `panel-body` `max-height` property.

[GIF of the intended behaviour](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24938324/38245616-860dbabc-3747-11e8-839f-91e045b794d0.gif)

This works well only on Chrome/Firefox, other browsers are experiencing lags/stutters.
I wondered if its possible to solve this issue with CSS alone, Flexbox came to mind and this is what i got:

```
.drawer-pf {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
.panel-group, .panel, .panel-collapse {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
.panel-group {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
.panel-heading {
      flex: none;
    }
.panel {
      flex: none;
    }
.panel-expanded {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
.panel-collapse {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
.panel-expanded .panel-body {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 150px;  /* this sets a min-height for the scrolling contents  */
    }

.panel-expanded .drawer-pf-action {
  flex: none;
}
```

The result is not good enough and I think i'm missing something.

[Storybook](https://rawgit.com/gilad215/patternfly-react/storybook/feature/notif-drawer/index.html?knob-Expanded%20Drawer=false&knob-is%20Drawer%20Expandable=true&selectedKind=NotificationDrawer&selectedStory=Stateful%20Drawer%20Wrapper&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybooks%2Fstorybook-addon-knobs)

You can see the in the storybook the `Stateful Drawer Wrapper` to watch the wanted behaviour, the `Drawer Wrapper` doesn't contain the JS functionality and you can test CSS there.
Or you can clone [my branch](https://github.com/gilad215/patternfly-react/tree/feature-notifdrawer) and apply css to `/sass/patternfly-react/_notificationdrawer.scss`

Thanks for any help!